# Calculate date difference for the same table column in two consecutive records

Tags: ms-access

I'm writing a formula in Access where I want to minus date in the current row to the date in the upper row in the same column. As I'm very new to Access, I'm not able to figure out how can I assign a cell reference to it.

For example, like in Excel, we can put cell reference `=a3-a2`, how can we do it in Access.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that in Access. A database table is not worksheet. You can only work record-wise in a database. What you can do is to join the table to itself. But this works only if you have an appropriate field that tells you how the records are related, for instance like a record number

Table:

```
RecordNo, Date
```

The query goes like this

```
SELECT
    DateDiff('d', t1.Date, t2.Date) As Days
FROM
    myTable t1
    INNER JOIN myTable t2
        ON t1.RecordNo + 1 = t2.RecordNo
```

One basic rule in databases is that the table records have no natural order. I.e. they do not have a line number bound to them. The database engine can reorder the rows when the database is compacted. Therefore a table must always have a primary key that allows you to identify a record. If you need a specific order, you must have a column that reflects this order and that you can use in an `ORDER BY` clause in a query.